# POST to opened javascript window and have Flash close the window

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3

I created a Flash application that reads POST data from a form. A user clicks the button, and the data gets posted to the flash app in a new window (`_blank`). Now takes the data and then spins a wheel to give users a prize. If they don't win a message pops up letting them know they didn't win. If they don't win, clicking the OK button needs to close the browser window.

I've tried a number of solutions and it seems that the only way to get this done is to launch the window with javascript and then use `ExternalInterface.call('window.close');` to close the window from within the Flash actionscript (3) because otherwise the window won't close (I've tried just using window.close and window.close() with no luck)

I understand how to launch a new window with javascript, but I don't know how to simultaneously launch and POST data to that window (the Flash application has to have the POST data.

Is this the best solution? Is there a way to close a browser window easier than what I'm describing?

Demo can be viewed here: http://rgwheel.phase-change.org/click.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I get you right :) 
You want to somehow get POST data from parent window form into flashvars javascript object at your child window?

If I get you right, it is pretty simple: you can access parent's window data from child window. Just change javascript code at your child window from this:

```
var flashvars = {};
flashvars.spinID="12345";flashvars.prizeTier="1";flashvars.totalSpins="100";var params = {};
var attributes = {};
swfobject.embedSWF("rrw_new_Final_ianb.swf", "flashDiv", "775", "819", "10.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
```

Into this:

```
var flashvars = {};
// here you get access to the form of the parent window
var parentForm = window.opener.document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];

// and here you can populate your flashvars with values from that form's inputs:
flashvars.spinId = parentForm.spinID.value;
flashvars.prizeTier = parentForm.prizeTier.value;
// and so on. Of course, you can do it with any javascript framework

var params = {};
var attributes = {};
swfobject.embedSWF("rrw_new_Final_ianb.swf", "flashDiv", "775", "819", "10.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
```

Ah, and I beleive you need to use javascript to open new window, not form's target attribute. 
Like this:

```
<form action="/" method="post" onsubmit="window.open()">
```

You can customize size, position and other properties of the child window, like it is shown here: http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

Comment: Thanks. This definitely solves the problem. I also discovered that target="_blank" does also work. Seems as though JS can close that window because it isn't the parent window. Thanks again!

Comment: IMO, it rather strange, than logical, that target="_blank" opens child window.

Comment: I mean, it would make much more sense if target="_blank" would worked like "open link in new tab/window" - and would open completely independent window, connected with previous one only with it's history object.